# Return Promise.reject in ionic page

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise

I'm calling a service method from inside a component, which returns me a Promise. I want to do different things based on if the promise is resolved or rejected. I'm doing it like this:

**the function that calls the service method**

```
onAddProvider() {
  this.userInteraction.addContact(data.email, 'bp').then(
    successMessage => {
      doSomething();
    },
    failureMessage => {
      doSomethingElse();
    });
}
```

**the service method**

```
addContact(email: string, type: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!email.match(patterns.email)) {
      return Promise.reject('Bad email address');
    }

    let data = {
      to: email,
      from: this.dataStorage.data.id,
      type: type,
      date: new Date().getTime()
    };

    this.http.post(`${serverURL}action=sendAddRequest&token=${localStorage['token']}`, JSON.stringify(data))
      .map((res: Response) => res.text())
      .subscribe(response => {
        resolve('Request sent');
      });
  });
}
```

I was expecting the `failureMessage` function to run when Promise.reject is returned, but instead I get this error in the console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Bad email address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
return Promise.reject('Bad email address');
```

with

```
return reject('Bad email address');
```

Comment: @AlexandruPufan This is correct answer, in fact. Can you recreate the problem with this correction as fiddle/plunk? `Promise.reject('Bad email address')` creates uncaught promise and doesn't call `reject`, `then` will never be fired. `reject` does the opposite (it shouldn't be returned).

Comment: I agree, return reject is enough : )

Answer (score 0):

It can also be rejected throwing an error.

```
throw "Error";
```